# populate multiple dropdowns from sql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have php embedded in html to populate a `<select>` input from a SQL table. I have multiple dropdowns in the file that need to be populated in the same file.

Is there an easier way to do this than opening a new connection and executing a new query for each one?

Also, when I close the connection, the data from all but the last dropdown won't populate in the sql table I'm saving the form input in to.

```
<td>Analyst<br/><?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'crm') 
            or die ('Cannot connect to db');

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,'Select id, fname, lname FROM users');
    echo "<select name='analyist'>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {   
        unset($id, $fname, $lname, $name);
        $id = $row['id'];
        $fname = $row['fname']; 
        $lname = $row['lname'];
        $name = $fname.' '.$lname;
        echo '<option name="analyst" value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';   
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: So this loads the data into your select option list.  You say that the problem is that what they selected isn't saving back into the sql table.  Can you show the code that performs that save?